# Can't run app when including AWS frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm coding using swift and followed the AWS documentation:

1. Added the updated frameworks on the Objective-C Bridging header
2. Setup cognito on app delegate

after that, this is spitting out:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>
> "_deflate", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[NSData(AWSGZIP) awsgzip_gzippedDataWithCompressionLevel:] in AWSCore(AWSGZIP.o)
> ```
>
> "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[NSData(AWSGZIP) awsgzip_gzippedDataWithCompressionLevel:] in AWSCore(AWSGZIP.o)
> ```
>
> "*deflateInit2*", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[NSData(AWSGZIP) awsgzip_gzippedDataWithCompressionLevel:] in AWSCore(AWSGZIP.o)
> ```
>
> "_inflate", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[NSData(AWSGZIP) awsgzip_gunzippedData] in AWSCore(AWSGZIP.o)
> ```
>
> "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[NSData(AWSGZIP) awsgzip_gunzippedData] in AWSCore(AWSGZIP.o)
> ```
>
> "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  -[NSData(AWSGZIP) awsgzip_gunzippedData] in AWSCore(AWSGZIP.o)
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Using Xcode 7.0

How can I fix this?

Comment: Added libz.tbd and it dissapears. Wonder if that did it

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `libsqlite3.dylib` and `libz.dylib` and `SystemConfiguration.framework`. See [Set Up the SDK for iOS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html#frameworks) for more details.